# Does the Facebook Connect oauth access_token reliably contain the facebook user id?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a facebook connect app all set up using oauth and after the final
transaction I receive an access_token that looks something like -

559514387926|f53be3fc76b8e243aaf2944b-**502835064**|moXh_HOIga8b32txRdwkan-5NW9.

The part in bold seems to be facebook user id of the current user. I checked this
with all the access_tokens of the users I have thus far and it matches in every case.

Is there any documentation that states that this is a reliable way to obtain
the facebook user id ?

I want to use the facebook user id directly to make leaner calls for existing users
pulling only picture and pulling a lot more data for a first time user.

Comment: i think it is not a good idea to try parse this token. since fb develop team decide to change its format - you will be ought to rewrite your application. there are "legal" ways to retrieve the current user's id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not parse the token, this is bad practise and since Facebook is in the middle of adding new features to the Graph API it is very susceptible to breaking changes. Make an API call to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...
```

And then parse out the id parameter and use that from then on!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct option, ended up sacrificing a little bit of performance for the documented approach. thanks.